# Extracting text from dataset

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am working on a dataset in which I need to extract all the available dates. Dates can be of the following format:

```
04/20/2009; 04/20/09; 4/20/09; 4/3/09
Mar-20-2009; Mar 20, 2009; March 20, 2009; Mar. 20, 2009; Mar 20 2009;
20 Mar 2009; 20 March 2009; 20 Mar. 2009; 20 March, 2009
Mar 20th, 2009; Mar 21st, 2009; Mar 22nd, 2009
Feb 2009; Sep 2009; Oct 2010
6/2008; 12/2009
2009; 2010
```

I wrote the below code:

```
df['dates'] = df['text'].str.extract(r'((?:\d{1,2}[/ ])?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec[a-z.,]*[- ])?(?:\d{1,2}[a-z-, /]{1,4})?(?:\d{2,4}))')
```

It is giving me the correct result except for some text like:

> TEXT                  OUTPUT
>
> Lab: B12 969 2007\n      12 969 #should give 2007
>
> for 35 years, sold in 1985\n          35 #should give 1985
>
> x 14 yrs who died i...          14 #should not be considered

I tried to change the extract code to

```
r'((?:\d{1,2}[/ ])?(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec[a-z.,]*[- ])?(?:\d{1,2}[a-z-, ]{1,4})?(?:[/]\d{2})?(?:\d{4})?)'
```

But with this entire result got bad

Comment: Try grouping the months pattern - https://regex101.com/r/Uebj4g/1 How varied are possible date patterns you want to cover?

Comment: its still the same

Comment: How come it is the same? Did you see the online demo? See also a grouped version: https://regex101.com/r/Uebj4g/2

Comment: Yes I saw, kindly check the string mentioned in blockquote. For those string it is not matching, or matching first occurrence which is not correct

Comment: Lab: B12 969 2007\n this should give output as 2007

Comment: But you need to use `str.findall(pattern)` to find all occurrences, not `extract` (I mentioned before that it only searches for the first occurrence, for a single match). Try something like `df['dates'] = df['text'].str.findall(r'((?:\d{1,2}[/ ])?(?:(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z.,]*[- ])?(?:\d{1,2}[a-z-, /]{1,4})?\d{2,4})')`, but you won't be able to run `pd.to_datetime()` since you need to have a single date per row, not lists of dates

Comment: I need to use to_datetime(). So i need to edit the regex so that It wont consider 12 969 and only consider year. As in the format of strings, only YYYY is there alone

Comment: Each line has only 1 valid occurance so no need of extractall

Comment: For the formats in your question you may use https://regex101.com/r/Uebj4g/3

Comment: Giving NaN for this string "y1974 (all)\n"

Comment: Sure,  because there is no year, but an alphanumeric string `y1974`. Try https://regex101.com/r/VE0Pb4/1 if your boundaries are numeric only.

Comment: Now "4-13-82 Other Child" giving NaN

Comment: Sure, you have not mentioned what formats you want to support. Regex will grow with time, when you find more and more formats.

Comment: Formats of date will be like the ones mentioned above. Text can come with it in different forms. That is why we are extracting the date right. In all the examples that I mentioned and in the Nan error examples too date format is like what is given but additional text is associated with it. And that is why we're using pandas in the first place right, to clean data

Comment: The dates you mentioned above are handled in my regex. You are keeping adding them.

Comment: Also now Regex has become so complicated for me to edit for it. I think this is the last case. I dont know how you did it. I want to do like you as well

Comment: yes I just noticed "4-13-82" this format wasn't there in the mentioned question. Sorry about that

Comment: I would be happy to accept your solution as you have provided me correct info for the given formats

Comment: If you could provide an explanation to the regex you sent last it would be great

Comment: so that i will modify it according to future needs

Comment: Ok, let me post. It will take some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your regex is that its constituents are all optional and it matches numbers that are not actually related to dates. You need to build a regex with obligatory parts to avoid matching arbitrary parts.

And this is tricky: there are different types of dates in your sample input. For those inputs, I'd recommend:

```
(?<!\d)((?<!\d[ \t])(?:A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Dec(?:ember)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ly|ne|[ln]))|Ma(?:rch|[ry])|Nov(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Sep(?:tember)?)(?:-\d{1,2}-\d{4}|(?:\.?\s*\d{1,2}(?:st|[rn]d|th)?,?)?\s*\d{4})|\d{1,2}\s+(?:A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Dec(?:ember)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ly|ne|[ln]))|Ma(?:rch|[ry])|Nov(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Sep(?:tember)?)\.?,?\s*\d{4}|(?:\d{1,2}/)?\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?|(?:19|20)\d{2})(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VE0Pb4/1). It matches:

- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind: no digit is allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `(` - start of the outer capturing group (necessary for `.str.extract`)

  - `(?<!\d[ \t])` - no digit followed with space or tab immediately to the left of the current location is allowed
  - `(?:A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Dec(?:ember)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ly|ne|[ln]))|Ma(?:rch|[ry])|Nov(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Sep(?:tember)?)` - names of months with their abbreviations
  - `(?:-\d{1,2}-\d{4}|(?:\.?\s*\d{1,2}(?:st|[rn]d|th)?,?)?\s*\d{4})` - either of the two alternatives:

    - `-\d{1,2}-\d{4}` - `-`, 1 or 2 digits, `-` and then 4 digits
    - `|` - or
    - `(?:\.?\s*\d{1,2}(?:st|[rn]d|th)?,?)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of:
    - `\.?` - an optional `.`
    - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
    - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
    - `(?:st|[rn]d|th)?` - an optional sequence of chars: `st`, `r` or `n` followed with `d`, or `th`
    - `,?` - an optional comma
    - `\s*\d{4}` - 0+ whitespaces and then 4 digits
- `|` - or

  - `\d{1,2}\s+` - 1 or 2 digits and then 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?:A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Dec(?:ember)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ly|ne|[ln]))|Ma(?:rch|[ry])|Nov(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Sep(?:tember)?)`  - names of months with their abbreviations (same as above)
  - `\.?` - an optional dot
  - `,?`  - an optional comma
  - `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
  - `\d{4}` - four digits
- `|` - or

  - `(?:\d{1,2}/)?` - an optional sequence of 1 or 2 digits and then `/`
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
  - `/` - `/`
  - `\d{2}(?:\d{2})?` - 2 digits and an optional sequence of 2 digits (it allows 2 or 4 digits but not 3)
- `|` - or

  - `(?:19|20)` - `19` or `20`
  - `\d{2}` - two digits
- `)` - end of the puter  caprturing group
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead: no digit is allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

In Python, you may define blocks for the pattern and build it dynamically:

```
months = r'(?:A(?:pr(?:il)?|ug(?:ust)?)|Dec(?:ember)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|J(?:an(?:uary)?|u(?:ly|ne|[ln]))|Ma(?:rch|[ry])|Nov(?:ember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Sep(?:tember)?)'
pattern = rf'(?<!\d)((?<!\d[ \t]){months}(?:-\d{{1,2}}-\d{{4}}|(?:\.?\s*\d{{1,2}}(?:st|[rn]d|th)?,?)?\s*\d{{4}})|\d{{1,2}}\s+{months}\.?,?\s*\d{{4}}|(?:\d{{1,2}}/)?\d{{1,2}}/\d{{2}}(?:\d{{2}})?|(?:19|20)\d{{2}})(?!\d)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html), it converts the most common date formats to datetime objects.

Comment: I am using that after extracting the date from data set

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://regexr.com/4odd2) pattern. My suggestion is, you should decompose the problem into pieces and try to match one pattern at a time. Because the regex for this problem is a bit messy and hard to cover all the edge cases with one expression.

I've included the sub regexps so you can refine them to validate the edge cases.

Comment: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1